# magento After registration (require email confirmation yes) redirect to cms page

Tags: php, magento

when I select the require email confirmation No in customer configuration in magento admin panel  , in accountcontroller.php changed

/////

class Mage_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

```
protected $_cookieCheckActions = array('loginPost', 'createpost');

protected function _getSession()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
}


public function preDispatch()
{
    // a brute-force protection here would be nice

    parent::preDispatch();

    if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
        return;
    }

    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $pattern = '/^(create|login|logoutSuccess|forgotpassword|forgotpasswordpost|confirm|confirmation)/i';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
    }
}

/**
 * Action postdispatch
 *
 * Remove No-referer flag from customer session after each action
 */
public function postDispatch()
{
    parent::postDispatch();
    $this->_getSession()->unsNoReferer(false);
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append(
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/account_dashboard')
    );
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Account'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Customer login form page
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        //$this->_redirect('registration-success');


         //Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true));

        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
         return;
    }

    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
    $this->renderLayout();


}

/**
 * Login post action
 */
public function loginPostAction()
{
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                if ($session->getCustomer()->getIsJustConfirmed()) {
                    $this->_welcomeCustomer($session->getCustomer(), true);
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                switch ($e->getCode()) {
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                        $value = Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                        $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value);
                        break;
                    case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                        break;
                    default:
                        $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
                $session->addError($message);
                $session->setUsername($login['username']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
            }
        } else {
            $session->addError($this->__('Login and password are required.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_loginPostRedirect();
}

/**
 * Define target URL and redirect customer after logging in
 */
protected function _loginPostRedirect()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    if (!$session->getBeforeAuthUrl() || $session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::getBaseUrl()) {

        // Set default URL to redirect customer to
        //$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
                    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('/marketplacepartner/partnerproducts/mydashboard/');
        // Redirect customer to the last page visited after logging in
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
                Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
            )) {
                $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME);
                if ($referer) {
                    $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
                    if ($this->_isUrlInternal($referer)) {
                        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($referer);
                    }
                }
            } else if ($session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
                $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
            }
        } else {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl());
        }
    } else if ($session->getBeforeAuthUrl() == Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl()) {
        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getDashboardUrl());
    } else {
        if (!$session->getAfterAuthUrl()) {
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
        }
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($session->getAfterAuthUrl(true));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
}

/**
 * Customer logout action
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->_getSession()->logout()
        ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl());

   // $this->_redirect('registration-success');

    $this->_redirect('*/*/logoutSuccess');
}

/**
 * Logout success page
 */
public function logoutSuccessAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Customer register form page
 */
public function createAction()
{
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('registration-success');
       // $this->_redirect('*/*');
        return;
    }

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Create customer account action
 */
public function createPostAction()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();
    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $errors = array();

        if (!$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer')) {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setId(null);
        }

        /* @var $customerForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
        $customerForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
        $customerForm->setFormCode('customer_account_create')
            ->setEntity($customer);

        $customerData = $customerForm->extractData($this->getRequest());

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
            $customer->setIsSubscribed(1);
        }

        /**
         * Initialize customer group id
         */
        $customer->getGroupId();

        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('create_address')) {
            /* @var $address Mage_Customer_Model_Address */
            $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
            /* @var $addressForm Mage_Customer_Model_Form */
            $addressForm = Mage::getModel('customer/form');
            $addressForm->setFormCode('customer_register_address')
                ->setEntity($address);

            $addressData    = $addressForm->extractData($this->getRequest(), 'address', false);
            $addressErrors  = $addressForm->validateData($addressData);
            if ($addressErrors === true) {
                $address->setId(null)
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_billing', false))
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping($this->getRequest()->getParam('default_shipping', false));
                $addressForm->compactData($addressData);
                $customer->addAddress($address);

                $addressErrors = $address->validate();
                if (is_array($addressErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
                }
            } else {
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $addressErrors);
            }
        }

        try {
            $customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);
            if ($customerErrors !== true) {
                $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
            } else {
                $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
                $customer->setPassword($this->getRequest()->getPost('password'));
                $customer->setConfirmation($this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation'));
                $customerErrors = $customer->validate();
                if (is_array($customerErrors)) {
                    $errors = array_merge($customerErrors, $errors);
                }
            }

            $validationResult = count($errors) == 0;

            if (true === $validationResult) {
                $customer->save();

                Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                    array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                );

                 if ($customer->isConfirmationRequired()) {
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
                        'confirmation',
                        $session->getBeforeAuthUrl(),
                        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                    );
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));

                    $this->_redirect('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true));
                    //$this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true)));
                   // $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
                    return;


                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));


                } else {
                    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $url = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer);

                    $this->_redirectSuccess($url);
                  return;
                }
            } else {
                $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                if (is_array($errors)) {
                    foreach ($errors as $errorMessage) {
                        $session->addError($errorMessage);
                    }
                } else {
                    $session->addError($this->__('Invalid customer data'));
                }
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($e->getCode() === Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_EXISTS) {
                $url = Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');
                $message = $this->__('There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.', $url);
                $session->setEscapeMessages(false);
            } else {
                $message = $e->getMessage();
            }
            $session->addError($message);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost())
                ->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot save the customer.'));
        }
    }

    $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/create', array('_secure' => true)));
}

/**
 * Add welcome message and send new account email.
 * Returns success URL
 *
 * @param Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer
 * @param bool $isJustConfirmed
 * @return string
 */
protected function _welcomeCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $isJustConfirmed = false)
{
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
        $this->__('Thank you for registering with %s.', Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName())
    );

    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
        $isJustConfirmed ? 'confirmed' : 'registered',
        '',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
    );


    if ($this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl()) {
        $successUrl = $this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
    }
    $successUrl = Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true));
    return $successUrl;
}

/**
 * Confirm customer account by id and confirmation key
 */
public function confirmAction()
{
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
    try {
        $id      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        $key     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('key', false);
        $backUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back_url', false);
        if (empty($id) || empty($key)) {
            throw new Exception($this->__('Bad request.'));
        }

        // load customer by id (try/catch in case if it throws exceptions)
        try {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
            if ((!$customer) || (!$customer->getId())) {
                throw new Exception('Failed to load customer by id.');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($this->__('Wrong customer account specified.'));
        }

        // check if it is inactive
        if ($customer->getConfirmation()) {
            if ($customer->getConfirmation() !== $key) {
                throw new Exception($this->__('Wrong confirmation key.'));
            }

            // activate customer
            try {
                $customer->setConfirmation(null);
                $customer->save();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                throw new Exception($this->__('Failed to confirm customer account.'));
            }

            // log in and send greeting email, then die happy
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
            $successUrl = $this->_welcomeCustomer($customer, true);
            $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true)));

           // $this->_redirectSuccess($backUrl ? $backUrl : $successUrl);
            return;
        }
```

//$this->_redirect('registration-success');
            // die happy
            $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true)));
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // die unhappy
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
            return;
        }
    }

```
/**
 * Send confirmation link to specified email
 */
public function confirmationAction()
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }

    // try to confirm by email
    $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
    if ($email) {
        try {
            $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
            if (!$customer->getId()) {
                throw new Exception('');
            }
            if ($customer->getConfirmation()) {
                $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmation', '', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Please, check your email for confirmation key.'));
            } else {
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('This email does not require confirmation.'));
            }
            $this->_getSession()->setUsername($email);
            $this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure' => true)));
           //$this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure' => true)));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Wrong email.'));
            $this->_redirectError(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('email' => $email, '_secure' => true)));
        }
        return;
    }

    // output form

    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('accountConfirmation')
        ->setEmail($this->getRequest()->getParam('email', $email));

    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->renderLayout();


}

/**
 * Forgot customer password page
 */
public function forgotPasswordAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('forgotPassword')->setEmailValue(
        $this->_getSession()->getForgottenEmail()
    );
    $this->_getSession()->unsForgottenEmail();

    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->renderLayout();
}






if ($this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl()) {
    $successUrl = $this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
}
$successUrl = Mage::getUrl('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true));
return $successUrl;
```

Above code is working fine for redirect to cms page (without email confirmation option NO).

But I want to redirect to cms page when the require email confirmation option is YES.

Answer (score 0):

In `AccountController.php` you will find a function `public function createPostAction()` on line number 259.

In this function on line number 346, update below code:

```
$this->_redirectSuccess(Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true)));
```

With your cms page redirection:

```
$this->_redirect('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true));
```

Comment: index page (click my account ) that link

Comment: I have updated code, try this. This is magento core redirection function.

Comment: when i comment the line also text is showing ($session->addSuccess($this->__('Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email please <a href="%s">click here</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($customer->getEmail())));)

Comment: below this line you have to edit code, why you are sharing this line? Update your post with updated code(complete function code).

Comment: add this code `$this->_redirect('registration-success');` in stead of `$this->_redirect('registration-success', array('_secure'=>true));` and comment all line below this redirection code.

Comment: not directing add this ($this->_redirect('registration-success');) problem was where is line is coming from Account confirmation is required. Please, check your email for the confirmation link. To resend the confirmation email pleaseclick here" when comment line also same line is showing

Comment: No.. Have a good luck... try n try, may be you are missing something. This is the basic redirection in magento.